# VB Script referencing a Variable which is defined from a macro

Tags: vbscript

I need some help with this VB script (edit: it is being used in QlikView)- it is copying a file to a different location (checks if the file already exists in the destination folder).

It works when the source filename and location is hardcoded but this is going to be a variable which is defined in a different macro.

So the source filename and location will be defined by varFileOpen.

Basically in the code, instead of:

```
SourceFile = "C:\file_path\file_name.txt"
```

to be like this:

```
SourceFile = varFileOpen
```

where varFileOpen has been defined from a different SUB (it is the full file path).... I can't get it to work?

Sub that creates the varFileOpen:

```
'Sub to get open file dialog
SUB ShowOpen
OpenSave "varFileOpen", 0, "Text file (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*", "h:\", "Select a file to open"
END SUB
' Sub to show browse folder dialog
SUB Folder (objVariable)
ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
SET objShell = CREATEOBJECT("Shell.Application")
SET objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder (WINDOW_HANDLE, TITLE, OPTIONS, ROOT)
SET objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
strPathAndFile = objFolderItem.Path
SET objSavePath = ActiveDocument.Variables(objVariable)
objSavePath.SetContent strPathAndFile, TRUE
ON ERROR GOTO 0 
END SUB

' Sub to show open/save dialog
SUB OpenSave (objVariable, intType, strFilter, strInitialDirectory, strDialogText)   
' Create objects
SET objShell = CREATEOBJECT("WScript.Shell")
SET objFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTempDir = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
strTempFile = strTempDir & "\" & objFSO.GetTempName
' Temporary powershell script file to be invoked
strPSFile = tempFile & ".ps1"
' Temporary file to store standard output from command
strPSOutFile = tempFile & ".txt"
' Create script to run
strPSScript = strPSScript & "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(""System.windows.forms"") | Out-Null" & vbCRLF
' Check type (Open (0) or Save (1))
IF intType = 1 THEN
    strPSScript = strPSScript & "$dlg = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog" & vbCRLF
ELSE
    strPSScript = strPSScript & "$dlg = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog" & vbCRLF
END IF                  
' Set initial directory
strPSScript = strPSScript & "$dlg.initialDirectory = " & CHR(34) & strInitialDirectory & CHR(34) & vbCRLF
' Set file filter/s
strPSScript = strPSScript & "$dlg.filter = " & CHR(34) & strFilter & CHR(34) & vbCRLF
strPSScript = strPSScript & "$dlg.FilterIndex = 1" & vbCRLF
' Set dialog text 
strPSScript = strPSScript & "$dlg.Title = " & CHR(34) & strDialogText & CHR(34) & vbCRLF
' Show help (seems it must be set to true)
strPSScript = strPSScript & "$dlg.ShowHelp = $True" & vbCRLF
' Show the dialog
strPSScript = strPSScript & "$dlg.ShowDialog() | Out-Null" & vbCRLF
strPSScript = strPSScript & "Set-Content """ &strPSOutFile & """ $dlg.FileName" & vbCRLF
' Write result
SET objResultFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strPSFile, TRUE)
objResultFile.WriteLine(strPSScript)
objResultFile.Close
SET objResultFile = NOTHING
' Run command in PowerShell
strPSCMD = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted &'" & strPSFile & "'"
objShell.Run strPSCMD, 0, TRUE
' Open result file and read result
SET objResultFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strPSOutFile, 1, 0, -2)
strPathAndFile = objResultFile.ReadLine
objResultFile.Close
SET objResultFile = NOTHING
' Add to result to variable
 SET objSavePath = ActiveDocument.Variables(objVariable)
 objSavePath.SetContent strPathAndFile, TRUE
' Delete temp-files
objFSO.DeleteFile(strPSFile)
objFSO.DeleteFile(strPSOutFile)
END SUB
```

The above code opens explorer & you are able to select a file and the path is copied - varFileOpen.

The following SUB moves the file:

```
SUB movefile
Const DestinationFile = "c:\destfolder\anyfile.txt"
Const SourceFile = "C:\file_path\file_name.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
    'Check to see if the file is read-only
    If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then 
        'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\destfolder\", True
    Else 
        'The file exists and is read-only.
        'Remove the read-only attribute
        fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
        'Replace the file
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\destfolder\", True
        'Reapply the read-only attribute
        fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
    End If
Else
    'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
    fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\destfolder\", True
End If
Set fso = Nothing
END SUB
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the value into the `Sub` for it to have scope, which means you will need to define the sub like this so that it accepts a parameter

```
Public Sub MySub(byVal SourceFile)
```

`ByVal` just means you pass the Value of the variable rather than the actual variable itself.

And you would call it from the other sub with

```
MySub varFileOpen
```

EDIT:  Based on the code displayed above, you would need to change `Sub movefile` to `Sub movefile(byVal SourceFile)` and remove the `Const` delaration of SourceFile.  Once that was done, all you would have to do is change whatever is calling `movefile` (I can't see anything in the code you've posted doing this?) to call it with `movefile varToOpen` instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.  I have added the code to my question, could you point where I should place the new sub?  Many thanks

Comment: See edited answer for details.  I can't see anything in either of your code posts that actually calls the `movefile` sub?

Comment: I don't understand how 'SourceFile' will now equate to what 'varFileOpen' is?  This script is going in QlikView and the macro is called from a button, which is named the SUB name... it was called 'MoveFile'. Thanks

Comment: Ok... looks like we need to clarify things a bit as this is the first mention of Qlikview, and I'm not familiar with that tool...  The first sub defines varFileOpen to be whatever file the user has selected?  MoveFile needs to know what that value is.  Perhaps you can have the button code call the first sub to retrieve the value for varFileOpen and then use it to perform the MoveFile operation?

Answer (score 0):

Try my CustomFileDialog.

**Usage:**

```
Dim  fDialog
Set fDialog = New CustomFileDialog
fDialog.FilterString = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
fDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
fDialog.DialogText = "Select a file to open"
fDialog.Show
fDialog.MoveFile "C:\stackoverflow\temp\New File Name.TXT"
```

**CustomFileDialog**

```js
Class CustomFileDialog
 Public SourceFile
 Public FilterString
 Public InitialDirectory
 Public DialogText
 
 Public Sub Show
  Set toolkit = CreateObject("Vbsedit.toolkit")
  Files = toolkit.OpenFileDialog(InitialDirectory, FilterString, False,  DialogText)
  If UBound(Files) >= 0 Then
   SourceFile = Files(0) 
  Else 
   SourceFile = ""
  End If
 End Sub
 
 Public Sub MoveFile(DestinationFile)
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then   fso.DeleteFile DestinationFile, True
  fso.CopyFile SourceFile, DestinationFile, True
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas.  You say run the sub movefile....... but the "C:\file_path\file_name.txt" (the source file) is unknown - Sub OpenSave allows me to select a folder I want moving.